# How to get the redirected URL in Web Scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

All I want is the redirected url after requesting the actual url. This is the actual url `https://metric.picodi.net/us/r/19761`, when I hit enter on browser using this url it redirects me to a url like this

`https://www.overstock.com/?AID=11557584&PID=9096967&SID=5e479aea42dd4d2c85183aa2&cjevent=2e4090483d7d3c3db27e63d14903c327c7718b978cf0dfa24&entrytrigger=noshow&exittrigger=noshow&fp=F&utm_source=cj&utm_medium=affiliates`

I have tried to implement it like this but it s giving me the same url

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://metric.picodi.net/us/r/19761', allow_redirects=True)
>>> print(r.url)
https://metric.picodi.net/us/r/19761
>>> r.history
[]
```

I have also tried the following -

```
>>> r = requests.head('https://metric.picodi.net/us/r/19761', allow_redirects=True)
>>> print(r.url)
https://metric.picodi.net/us/r/19761
>>> r.history
[]
```

Comment: check what you get in `r.text` - maybe there is warning for bots and you may need to use header `User-Agent`  to pretend real web browser. Or there is JavaScript code which redirect to other page - `requests` can't execute JavaScript but you can try to get url from JavaScript and run requests manually.

Comment: @furas we need to have a look on how to render `GET/HEAD` request on the fly. as i completely sure that's can be done on the fly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's due to `JavaScript` which is handling the redirection dynamically after page loads.

Therefore, you can achieve that using `Selenium`

Something like the following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
link = 'https://metric.picodi.net/us/r/19761'

driver.get(link)
print(driver.current_url)

driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
https://www.overstock.com/?AID=11557584&PID=9096967&SID=5e63c10642dd4d26f7549875&cjevent=121071440d708c3db27e63d55903c327c7718b9633548769c&entrytrigger=noshow&exittrigger=noshow&fp=F&utm_source=cj&utm_medium=affiliates
```

> Note that you might use `requests_html` which will be a good friend to render the `JavaScript` for you.