# Site redirects despite receiving 200 OK?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm using the [cloudscraper](https://github.com/venomous/cloudscraper) library on the URL https://monroe.county-taxes.com/public/search/property_tax?search_query=1573108&redirect=1573108

The site redirects to https://monroe.county-taxes.com/public/real_estate/parcels/1573108/bills?parcel=ef360da9-e509-11eb-9467-005056818710&qid=27a7b62cf21f5b6bf80d9b106b6e286f on my browser, which is the target site that I want to extract the data from. However, the responses from `network` tab are all `200 OK` and I could not find a trace of anything that hints to this URL from the one above. What might be happening here?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
import cloudscraper

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
r = scraper.get("https://monroe.county-taxes.com/public/search/property_tax?search_query=1573108&redirect=1573108")
print(r.text)
```

Edit: I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60576039/how-to-get-the-redirected-url-in-web-scraping) solution but due to Selenium's subpar speed, I prefer to leave it as the very last resort and looking for a different way.

Comment: It seems that javascript is performing the redirect. Which intern doesn't yield a 3xx code in the network tab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the redirected URL in Web Scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60576039/how-to-get-the-redirected-url-in-web-scraping)

Comment: @tevemadarUnfortunately, no. That was one of the first things I tried but it didn't follow the redirect hence `.history` is empty. Selenium might work but I am constrained to not use it due to its speed and the sheer quantity of data to scrape.